# neo4j: cypher to identify unresolved edges

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My Edge object is like this:

```
class Edge {
   public long srcNodeId;
   public long destNodeId;
}
```

Given a `List<Edge>`, is it possible to return all edges either src OR dest OR both nodes doesn't exist, using a single cypher query?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to concoct a Cypher query that checks both the srcNodeId and the destNodeId for each edge in your list , and see if these fellas match up with any existing node in the database.

Here's a query that can get this job done:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT (ID(n) IN $srcNodeIds) OR NOT (ID(n) IN $destNodeIds)
RETURN n
```

In this query, $srcNodeIds and $destNodeIds are parameters you'll pass into the query that represent your lists of source node IDs and destination node IDs, respectively. The query is checking if any nodes exist with IDs that are NOT in these lists. Any nodes that are returned from this query would be the unresolved ones , i.e., they exist in your Edge objects but not in the actual database.

Just remember to pass in the srcNodeIds and destNodeIds as parameters when you're running this query. For instance , in the Neo4j Java driver, it might look something like this:

```
List<Long> srcNodeIds = edges.stream().map(edge -> edge.srcNodeId).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Long> destNodeIds = edges.stream().map(edge -> edge.destNodeId).collect(Collectors.toList());

Session session = driver.session();

Map<String , Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("srcNodeIds" , srcNodeIds);
params.put("destNodeIds" , destNodeIds);
```

StatementResult result = session.run(query , params);
Now , keep in mind that this query might take a while if you've got a massive graph, because it's essentially scanning through the whole kit and caboodle.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$edges` is a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) with a list of edges:

```
UNWIND $edges AS e
OPTIONAL MATCH (src) WHERE ID(src) = e.srcNodeId
OPTIONAL MATCH (dest) WHERE ID(dest) = e.destNodeId
RETURN
  e.srcNodeId AS srcNodeId, src IS NOT NULL AS srcExists,
  e.destNodeId AS destNodeId, dest IS NOT NULL AS destExists
```